# Ruby on Rails get paramenter from URL on View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'd like to get the paramenter from the URL on my view/html.

For example, I'm showing an specific item from my data base, and the URL is like this: "http://localhost:3000/menus/index.%23%3CMenu::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f50ed153250%3E?id=6"

What I want is: when I click on the New Button of that specific item, the form opens with the URL "http://localhost:3000/menus/new", but I want somehow pass that id=6 to this NEW view.

I am using this code on the html to open the form: `<%= link_to 'Novo', new_menu_path %>`

I also tried: `<%= link_to 'Novo', new_menu_path(@menus, :id) %>`, but the id param is always null/empty.

How do I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well `:id` is just a symbol, you need to tell the route helper what to bind to it.   For example

```
<%= link_to 'Novo', new_menu_path(id: params[:id]) %>
```

which should give you something like `/menus/new?id=6`

Answer (score 2):

To pass an extra param to an url when you define a `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'Novo', new_menu_path(id: @menu.id, other_param: "hello") %>
```

will generate `http://localhost:3000/menus/new?id=6&other_param=hello`

this will add the following to the `params` hash

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"6", "other_param"=>"hello"}
```